Problem check if input form has been completed using isset()
Hi I have been struggling with this WordPress metabox designed to same attributes within the edit 'product' admin screen of the Woocommerce plugin. The code is below and written into the child theme's functions.php file.
The aim is to record for a given product 'x' what parts are required based on their SKU and the Quantity required.
The code throws no errors and enters the the form data into the table 'postmeta'. HOWEVER if the form elements are not empty and the the post is 'updated' then empty fields are also entered into 'postmeta'.
I have tried numerous ways to prevent this but everything has failed, either entering no data or empty data. The 'If' statement does not work. I have tried to use empty() rather then isset().
Output of several attempts
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'wizpart_meta_box_init' );

// meta box functions for adding the meta box and saving the data

        function wizpart_meta_box_init() {  
        // create our custom meta box
        add_meta_box( 'wizpart_meta', // Unique ID
                     'Parts Information', // Title
                     'wizpart_meta_box', // Callback function
                     'product', //  post type
                     'normal', // Context
                     'high'  // Priority
                    );
        }


function wizpart_meta_box( $post, $c ) {
// Leading HTML

    
    // retrieve the custom meta box values
    $wizpart_meta_full = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_wizpart_data');
    echo var_dump($wizpart_meta_full).'<br />';
        if (! empty($wizpart_meta_full)) {
            foreach( $wizpart_meta_full as $entry){ 
            // print out each part
            print 'Product comprises '.$entry['quant'].' units of '.$entry['sku'].' <br />';
            }
        }   

    //nonce for security
    wp_nonce_field( 'meta_box_save', 'wizpart_plugin' );

   // Form HTML
    echo '<div class = wizpart>';
    echo '<table>';
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td> Enter correct SKU of part: </td>';
    echo '<td> <input type="text" name="wizpart[sku]" value = "" size="5" > </td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td> Enter quantity of parts required as integer: </td>';
    echo '<td> <input type="text" name="wizpart[quant]" value = "" size="5" > </td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    echo '</table>';
    echo '</div>';  
}

// hook to save  meta box data when the post is saved
add_action( 'save_post', 'wizpart_save_meta_box' );

function wizpart_save_meta_box( $post_id) {
        
        if ( get_post_type( $post_id ) == 'product' && isset( $_POST[wizpart] )) {
    
    
            // if auto saving skip saving our meta box data
            if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return;
            //check nonce for security
            wp_verify_nonce( 'meta_box_save', 'wizpart_plugin' );
            // store data in an array
            // Get the post ID from the from SKU
            $wizpart_data = $_POST['wizpart'];
            // use array map function to sanitize options

            $wizpart_data = array_map( 'sanitize_text_field', $wizpart_data) ;

            // save the meta box data as post meta using the post ID as a unique prefix
            // using add_post_meta to increment the array with values
            add_post_meta( $post_id, '_wizpart_data', $wizpart_data );
            
    }
}

I do not know how to debug this as for some reason no echo or print works from the function wizpart_save_meta_box( $post_id) {}
Update: Inserting the 'if' statement does prevent empty data being entered.
function wizpart_save_meta_box( $post_id) {
    
    if ( get_post_type( $post_id ) == 'product' && isset( $_POST['wizpart'] )) {


        // if auto saving skip saving our meta box data
        if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return;
        //check nonce for security
        wp_verify_nonce( 'meta_box_save', 'wizpart_plugin' );
        // store data in an array
        // Get the post ID from the from SKU
        $wizpart_data = $_POST['wizpart'];
        // use array map function to sanitize options
        if (($wizpart_data['sku'] == "")|| ($wizpart_data['quant'] == "")) return;
        $wizpart_data = array_map( 'sanitize_text_field', $wizpart_data) ;

        // save the meta box data as post meta using the post ID as a unique prefix
        // using add_post_meta to increment the array with values
        add_post_meta( $post_id, '_wizpart_data', $wizpart_data );
        
}

}
Any help really appreciated.
To be able to record data only when the form is filled out.

One thing about your code but may not answer your question. You use wrong syntax. You have to use $array['key'] NOT $array[key], check your code $_POST[wizpart] and everywhere else.

Thanks but unfortunately this produces a critical error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected identifier "sku", expecting "," or ";" in.... Using && isset( $_POST['wizpart'] )  doesn't affect the functioning of the code?

Using 'code' && isset( $_POST['wizpart'] ) 'code' doesn't affect the functioning of the code?

Using $_POST['wizpart'] is already correct and it should not produce another error. Sometimes just calling $array['key'] while have no key name key may cause undefined error but it is not possible to produce Parse error, syntax error. Prevent by using isset() or array_key_exists().
